# Change text box text when user clicks out or tabs out

Tags: jquery

I have a reg page and I do not have access to the database and I need to change values based on users entries.

If a user enters St. Louis in a city text box can I change the "St." to "Saint" as they leave the text box for the next field?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: search for `blur` but do follow what @AlonEitan mentioned

Comment: @Graigue, you have been a member for 2 years now, you really need to learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) otherwise you may be [blocked from asking more questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: It's a really simple question with a very simple answer, so no worries about not adding any code yourself this time. However, this was very simple to understand and help with. Next time, you may not receive an answer at all because people can't write a lot of code for you here without you helping them out a little first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.myInput').on('blur', function(e) {
    var providedCityName = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    // String contains 'St.'
    if (providedCityName.indexOf("st.") >= 0) {
        providedCityName = providedCityName.replace("st.", "Saint");

        // Put 'Saint...' in the input field
        $(this).val(providedCityName);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4qng1d3/)